# Using my linked list code in a new c program

Tags: c

Apologies in advance since this seems extremely basic.

I have my linked list file, linkedList.c, and I would like to include it in my new c file so that I don't have to code the whole linked list in again. In Java I just had to place it in the same folder and then I could create an object of the class linkedList in the new file however C doesn't seem to work this way. If I try to use

```
#include "linkedLIst.c"
```

at the start of my new file then I receive errors since main has now been defined twice along with my Boolean variable. How exactly do I go about solving this?

Comment: This is standard C compilation. Something you can find out about in any C book or by doing a search. Stackoverflow is not a suitable place to ask about tutorial style questions.

Comment: For one, a reusable module should not contain a main. Second, C requires you to `include` only an interface, and then [link your program](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html).

Comment: You declare the functions in a header (`linkedList.h`). You define linked list the functions in a source file (`linkedList.c`) — without the `main()`.  You put the old main program in another source file (`main1.c`), which includes `linkedList.h`.  You put your new main program in another source file (`main2.c`) which also includes `linkedList.h`.  You compile `linkedList.c` to an object file `linkedList.o`.  You link that object file with `main1.c` to build the old program; you link that object file with `main2.c` to build the new program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could `#include` any kind of (syntactically valid) C code, but you generally should not (by convention) include a `.c` file. Read more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

In practice, you should consider making some [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) (to be [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) for reuse), and separate your shared code into a `.h` header file (containing *definitions*) that you would `#include` for re-using and an implementation `.c` file. Of course don't define any `main` in the shared source code. In some simple cases and on some operating systems, you might also share a *single* (or some few) [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (and related header files).

Your shared header would declare functions and `extern` variables (and `#define` some macros). It could also contain the *definition* (with their body) of *short* `static inline` functions.

Your shared implementation would *define* these (and others) functions and variables.

**C programming entails a lot of *conventions*** (and you need to define your own ones). **Look at existing examples** (some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) source code from [github](http://github.com), or from a Linux distribution). For reusable container libraries, look into [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) (from GTK) and also [sglib](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/) (which uses a lot of preprocessor tricks) and many others.

Because C does not have any notion of [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) it is wise (for readability and other reasons) to have a consistent naming convention, e.g. starting all the public names (of functions and variables and macros in headers) of your library by some common prefix.

Comment: Of course, you need to ensure that both your new `.c` file *and* the `linkedList.c` file are both passed-in to your compiler.

Comment: @Dai: in practice, you will like the `linkedList.o` object file or the `-llinkedList` library to other programs (and also `#include "linkedList.h"` there)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a header file, `linkedList.h`, and declare your linked list function prototypes in there, which you probably already have defined in you `linkedList.c` file. And then, you can use `'#include linkedList.h'` to reuse your code.

Comment: You forgot to explain how to reuse `linkedList.o`